# SSH Connection refused after modifying iptables

Tags: ssh, iptables

Yesterday night I was messing with my iptables doing this specific commands:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

nothing really harmful if I'm correct. And then my ssh connexion went down. Tried to reboot the server, but it kept saying

```
ssh: connect to host X.X.X.X port 22: Connection refused
```

I tried to boot into rescue mode, mount /dev/sda2 /mnt, chroot /mnt and just flushed the iptables. But still not working. It looks like nothing that need external access is working anymore...

I tried to remove (--purge) openssh-client and server and reinstall, still the same.

**EDIT:**

So as Khaled mentioned I tried to add

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

to my iptables in rescue mode, then save it to /etc/iptables.rules but it doesn't work.
I also tried to add these instructions to /etc/rc.local to flush the iptables at boot:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -X
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -X
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Still doesn't work.

Also this is the result when I (still in chrooted rescue mode) try to launch ssh with -d option

```
/etc/init.d/ssh start -d
[....] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshddebug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.7, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: private host key: #2 type 3 ECDSA
debug1: private host key: #3 type 4 ED25519
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
Cannot bind any address.
 failed!
```

but that seems pretty logical to me (as a big noob) since I am already using ssh on the rescue mode...

**EDIT 2:**

As asked, here the result of the telnet when the server is up and not in rescue mode:

```
telnet X.X.X.X 22
Trying X.X.X.X...
telnet: connect to address X.X.X.X: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Comment: Flushing the rules as the last stage of booting (with a view to restoring your access to the running system) is a good idea, but in the changes you made to `rc.local`, you don't need `sudo`, as `rc.local` runs as root.  However, you may well need the path; try replacing `sudo ` with `/sbin`.  Also, you need to flush the filter table as well (`iptables -F`).

Comment: Thanks for your help MadHatter! But it doesn't seems to work better with your changes... I'm kinda desperate now...

Comment: Could you update your question to show the command, and output, of `telnet server.ip 22` when the server is up and running?

Comment: Done! Telnet is also refusing connexion... And it's not only refusing on 22, it's refusing on every port that should be open and listening at boot (80 for exemple)...

Comment: I don't think this is firewall-related, because your old policy was `DROP`, and this is a tcp-reset, or equivalent.  It looks more like `sshd` isn't running, possibly as a result of the de-install/re-install.  You want to add a `/sbin/service sshd restart` to the end of the `rc.local`hack?

Comment: Scratch that, I wrote it before seeing your comment about no connections on *any* port.  I think you've roached your VPS while flailing around.  If this is a VPS that supports a remote console, you might learn something by wathcing it fail to boot; otherwise, I think it's delete-and-restore-from-backups time.

Comment: I don't have `/sbin/service` on my server (I'm running a debian 8) but the rc.local already contains `/etc/init.d/sshd start` at the end, isn't it supposed to be enough to start ssh at boot?

Comment: Also, is that normal that each time I boot in rescue mode and chroot my mounted disk, iptables -L return empty rules even though I added some in the previous rescue mode boot? I did iptables-save but it's like it doesn't count

Comment: When you're running in rescue mode, you're booted from a completely different environment, with your normal HDD mounted on a custom mount point.  You should not expect things to run normally under those conditions, nor should you expect them to be persistent.  If you'll forgive me, I think you may be out of your depth, and should probably seek professional assistance.

Answer (score 3):

The ruleset you posted does not allow any incoming connection to the server. You are only allowing traffic locally via loopback interface and `RELATED`, `ESTABLISHED` states. These are not enough to access the server. You need at least to allow SSH port using a rule lile:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Another important thing to note is the way you are executing these iptables commands. You should execute them as a script not one command at a time. By the time you enter the third command `sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP` you are dropping all incoming packets to your server and it becomes inaccessible. This is becase iptables command take effect immediately!

Usually, connection refused error is caused by a process not listening on the specified port or by an explicit iptables `REJECTR` rule (which is not the case here). If you can access the server, you need to make sure ssh server is running and listening on port 22. You can use:

```
sudo netstat -lnp | grep 22
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Khaled! I did add this to my now blank iptables but I still got the same reject when trying to connect...

Comment: @Chop: Please post the output of netstat as stated in the answer.

Comment: It doesn't return anything but I'm in rescue mode, I'm just mounting the disk and chrooting so I don't if it is supposed to work?

Also I tried to add to rc.local instructions to allow everything on the iptables and it still doesn't work...

Comment: I edited my post so you can see what I did. more clearly!